# Django Calculated fields do not appear in get_fields()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a calculated field in a model.

```
class SfShifts(models.Model):
    pr_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='pr_id__c')

    def _get_calculated_field(self):
        return {'cal': self.pr_id}
    calculated_field = property(_get_calculated_field)
```

But when I call `get_fields()` I don't get it.

```
field_list = [field.get_attname_column() for field in self.model._meta.get_fields()]
```

How can I get the calculated field name too?

Comment: it is not a model field, it is just a property method

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import inspect

field_list = [f for f, _ in inspect.getmembers(field) if f[0] != '_' ]
```

It will contain properties as well. However, it will also contain some additional stuff such as "validate_unique", "save" etc, but they are Django-related so can be tracked and excluded manually.

I.e.

```
django_reserved = set(x for x, _ in inspect.getmembers(models.Model))

# add properties that are not included in base model
django_reserved.add('DoesNotExist')
django_reserved.add('MultipleObjectsReturned')


field_list = [f for f, _ in inspect.getmembers(field) if f[0] != '_' and f not in django_reserved ]
```

This will give you only the list of fields/properties that are related to the specific model